# PHP Mysql MAX() returning wrong result

Tags: php, mysql

PHP:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(something) AS something FROM users");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$max =  $row["something"];
echo $max;
```

Mysql:

```
+-----------+----------+
| Something | Name     |
+-----------+----------+
| 9         | John     |
| 984       | Somebody |
| 1         | Who      |
```

Code results: 9, the question is why? Mysql "something" type is "text". My mysql table is bigger than this above, but it still results not the biggest "something".

Comment: What data type does  `something` have?

Comment: @juergend OP *""something" type is "text""*

Comment: There's your answer; it's not an int, it's text. MySQL doesn't do math on that type. Try and add ABC then multiply by JOHN ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Hello bud.

Comment: What I should use to get MAX in "text" type?

Comment: alter your column as `int`.

Comment: When you learn to count as a kid, you use numbers, not "text". Programming is the same, the maximum of a string means absolutly nothing...

Comment: I agree with @Fred-ii- in order to do any mathematical operations you need to set them to `INT` not `TEXT`

Comment: I was going to edit my comment earlier about casting it. Just saying. Wondering why you're using integers in a text column though to start with. Big question ? mark there.

Comment: If you can, you should [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) [statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead, and consider using PDO, [it's really not hard](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: @JayBlanchard the good ol `mysql` deprecation comment.

Comment: Until we get it hammered into reality @CodeGodie ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either do a math operation on the column to trigger an auto-cast

```
SELECT MAX(something * 1) AS something FROM users#
```

or cast explicitly with

```
SELECT MAX(cast(something as signed)) AS something FROM users
```

but even better - if that column only contains numbers then change the data type of that field ti `int` for instance.

Comment: care to explain this? I'm having a danish myself to satisfy my hungry tummy ;-)

Comment: why not set the columns to `INT` instead?

Comment: @CodeGodie I'm wondering that myself and why OP is using integers to start with.

Comment: Even if there's a reason why OP needs them as `TEXT`, it is just bad design from my perspective.

Comment: @ArnasMarnas As stated; it's bad design. This will mean that you will have to cast everytime you want to perform a mathematical operation, using MySQL's other aggregate functions. If you're in an early stage, best to rethink this. *My 2 cents of course*, which may be worth a pound of gold later on. Having to "cast", means more code for what's needed, including resources.